# Trying to set environment variables in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm trying to set the `%systemroot%` environment variable in PowerShell on Windows 10. It's not working.

Here's what I've tried and the results:

```
$env:SystemRoot = "C:\Windows"
echo %SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%

setx SystemRoot "C:\Windows"
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
echo %SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to restart the PowerShell command prompt due to the method your using to modify the system variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up PowerShell and DOS syntax.
`%SystemRoot%` is DOS syntax, the PowerShell syntax is `$env:SystemRoot`.

The following example will perhaps clarify the difference:

[image]

Please note that the change of the value of `SystemRoot` only applies
to this one PowerShell instance (is not system-wide).

Reference:
[How To Work with Environment Variables in PowerShell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/03/28/environment-variables-in-powershell.aspx).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification!